# insert an array into a single column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have an issue while I'm trying to create sending messages function. In case of multiple receivers, it seems to need adding an array of user ids into "Receiver" field. How could I handle this in both PHP side and MySQL side ? Or any further suggestions?

Comment: You should avoid inserting multiple values in a single field. Have a read about [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: @putvande: I'm looking for a specific PHP method. I've already thought about your suggestion.

Comment: But why do you say _it seems to need adding an array_. Is it not your database / function? Can you share some code.. makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @putvande: I still have no ideas how to deal with the situation of multiple receivers. In case of single receiver, it's so simple that I just need to insert only one id into "Receiver" field. However, when receivers are multiple, multiple rows could cause duplicate messages content.

Comment: please show us your code

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't want to insert an array. Instead, insert multiple rows.

```
INSERT INTO Message(id, recepient_id) VALUES (5, 12), (5, 13);
```

or something like this

Comment: In this case, it will render multiple messages if I make a query by each row.

Comment: "It"? If you cannot write a PHP code to correctly understand multiple rows with the same message id as belonging to one message, then you can try to `SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT recepient_id SEPARATOR ',') FROM Message GROUP BY id` or something like this.

Comment: I now completely understand your suggestion. I think your answer could be better if you added a little bit more details similar to this line "multiple rows with the same message id as belonging to one message". Thank you.